# How to use oracle $$PLSQL_LINE in a shell script?

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql, line-numbers

I want to log the line number of a stand alone block within a shell script.

I am trying to use the below code but its not working. Please let me know if there is a working solution for this.

```
#!/bin/ksh

result=`sqlplus -s $DATABASE <<EOF
SET SET HEAD OFF;
SET PAGES 0;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED;
SET DEFINE OFF;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Line number: '|| $$plsql_line);
END;
/
EOF`
echo $result
```

I get the following error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PLSQL_LINE" when expecting one of the following: 
) = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem => <an exponent (**)> <>
 or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec as between from using 
|| member submultiset The symbol "," was substituted for "PLSQL_LINE" to continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` needs to be escaped:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Line number: '|| \\$\\$plsql_line);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the here-document (starting with the first `<<EOF`) is expanding shell variables (anything beginning with a `$`).  You can suppress that behavior by

- putting a backslash before each `$`,
- or noting that the here document has no useful shell variables, by quoting the first `EOF`, e.g.,

  result=`sqlplus -s $DATABASE <<"EOF"

or

```
result=`sqlplus -s $DATABASE <<'EOF'
```

Further reading:

- [How to print “$” in here-document](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68419/how-to-print-in-here-document)